# Twilio whatstapp templates blocks newline

Tags: twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

Im using Twilio's whatsapp templates service, but when one of the strings has a newline, it fails to sent the message. tried to replace with /n and other options, didnt work.

how can i do this? it's kind of the point of my business, without this option i dont really have a point to use their service.

if someone knows another service that allows this, might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

WhatsApp message templates can contain line breaks but you need to make sure that the message contains the very same content -- including the same kind of line break (`\n` vs `\r` vs `\n\r`).

Another way of achieving the same result, is by using the [Content Editor and the Content API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content). This way you can define your templates in the Twilio Console and reference their SID in the program code.

```js
// Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install
// Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
// and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({
         contentSid: 'HXXXXXXXXX',
         from: 'MGXXXXXXXX',
         contentVariables: JSON.stringify({
           1: 'Name'
         }),
         to: 'whatsapp:+18551234567'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```